# Sorting a dictionary with multiple sized values

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that needs to be sorted. I understand that a dictionary cannot be sorted, so I am building a list to perform a sort based upon the index. The problem I am having is that there are duplicate values across multiple keys; also, the values can be multiple lists.

Dictionary:

```
my_dict = {
    '1' : ['Red', 'McDonald\'s'],
    '2' : [['Orange', 'Wendy\'s'], ['Purple', 'Cookout']],
    '3' : ['Yellow', 'Longhorn'],
    '4' : ['Green', 'Subway'],
    '5' : ['Blue', 'Chipotle'],
    '6' : ['Indigo', 'Taco Bell'],
    '7' : [['Violet', 'Steak n Shake'], ['Dark Red', 'Five Guys']],
    '8' : ['Dark Orange', 'Wendy\'s'],
    '9' : ['Aqua', 'Firehouse Subs'],
    '10' : ['Magenta', 'McDonald\'s'],
}
```

I need to be able to sort this by key(the number), the color, and the restaurant. The problem I am having is that printing has to be grouped when there are duplicates and I cannot figure out how to sort the list I generate properly.

Example of print by number:

```
1:
    Red, McDonald's

2:
    Orange, Wendy's
    Purple, Cookout

3:
    Yellow, Longhorn

...
```

Example of print by color:

```
Aqua:
    Firehouse Subs, 9

Blue:
    Chipotle, 5

Dark Orange:
    Wendy's, 8

...
```

My solution to this is to create a list with each of the keys and values in a list. I am still new, and I think this is not the correct way to iterate this dictionary, but it works for the given dictionary.

```
sorted_number = []
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if len(value[0][0]) > 1:
        working_list = (key, value[0][0], value[0][1], value[1][0], value[1][1])
        sorted_number.append(working_list)
    else:
        working_list = (key, value[0], value[1])
        sorted_number.append(working_list)

sorted_years = sorted(sorted_years, key=lambda y: y[0][0])
for i in sorted_years:
    print('{}:'.format(i[0]))
    if len(i) > 3:
         print('\t{}, {}'.format(i[1], i[2])
         print('\t{}, {}'.format(i[3], i[4]))
    else:
         print('\t{}, {}'.format(i[1], i[2]))
```

Because some values are multiple lists, the if/else statement determines if the value is one or two lists. This then will correctly produce a list of (number, color, restaurant) or (number, color, restaurant, color, restaurant) that can then sort the list by the number. The problem is when I attempt to sort by color or restaurant. I know that I can make the list be only three elements to make the sorting work properly, but when I go to print, I will end up with multiple 2's and 7's. The same result is with restaurant. Also, that does not solve the problem of multiple restaurants. I have searched and tested for about five days attempting different ways to unpack the dictionary, but this is the closest I have got to solving this problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

For clarity, here is the print iteration for numbers:

```
for i in sorted_number:
    print('{}:'.format(i[0]))
    if len(i) > 3:
        print('\t{}, {}'.format(i[1], i[2]))
        print('\t{}, {}'.format(i[3], i[4]))
    else:
        print('\t{}, {}'.format(i[1], i[2]))
```

Comment: Have you tried reading this https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0265/

Comment: @NitishKumar The values can be one or two lists. Unless there is something I am overlooking, the solution is to convert the dictionary into a list of three elements, then perform the sort.

Comment: Maybe you could use JSON

Comment: How do you want to place when sorting by color the item `'7' : [['Violet', 'Steak n Shake'], ['Dark Red', 'Five Guys']]`? Should it go after `'8' : ['Dark Orange', 'Wendy\'s']` (using `'Dark Red'`) or after `'1' : ['Red', 'McDonald\'s']` (using `'Violet'`)?

Comment: @SergeBallesta There really is no worry about placement, so long as when you iterate the list or tuple, you can print the information as described. My thoughts were to make a list like (5, Blue, Chipotle), but the problem is when you go to print, you will have duplicates on the sortby(e.g. 2 McDonald's). On duplicate entries for the sort, you should print like such:
McDonald's:
    Red, 1
    Magenta, 10

I cannot format the comment correctly to show proper indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to convert the dict into a list and homogenize the dict value in the form of array of tuple. Then using the [groupBy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function from itertools module you can group by the selected param.

```
class RestourantSorter:
    def __init__(self, source):
        self._rList = []
        """ Dict to list [(key, color, restourant name), ....] """
        for key, value in source.items():
            for color, rest in value if isinstance(value[0], list) else [value]:
                self._rList.append((key,color,rest))

    def _byIndex(self, x):
        return int(x[0])
    def _byColor(self, x):
        return x[1]
    def _byName(self, x):
        return x[2]

    def sort(self, sortFn):
        """ Sorted data [(key, [... values ...]), ....] """
        groups = []
        data = sorted(self._rList, key=sortFn)
        for k, g in groupby(data, sortFn):
            groups.append((k, list(g)))
        return groups

    def sortByIndex(self):
        return self.sort(self._byIndex)
    def sortByColor(self):
        return self.sort(self._byColor)
    def sortByName(self):
        return self.sort(self._byName)
```

Working [REPL](https://repl.it/@nicolavanoni/Sorter-class)

Comment: You kind person are amazing! I am still a student, and nothing covered so far in class has touched __init__ and self for building a class. We lightly touched on the topic of class building, and to be honest I may have defined something once or twice total. This is my first programming class, and I will definitely need to look further into class building; if that is even the proper terminology. I understand about 90% of what is happening with this class; however, I need to look into self and __init__ to fully grasp everything. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you are looking to change or apply different indexing, a dictionary isn't ideal. It can only have one key. If you use the number as a key, switching to indexing by color is difficult. That's not what dictionaries are optimized for.

You can use a custom class, but I prefer to use a 3rd party library designed for manipulating data. Here's an example with Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

chainer = chain.from_iterable

# calculate numeric keys including repeats, flat list
keys = list(chainer([k]*(len(v) if isinstance(v[0], list) else 1) \
                    for k, v in my_dict.items()))

# calculate color-name combinations, list of lists, each sublist of length 2
vals = list(chainer((v if isinstance(v[0], list) else [v] \
                    for v in my_dict.values())))

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=['color', 'name'], index=keys)
```

You can then group by numeric key, color, etc, for your desired outputs, for which there are many solutions available on SO. Sorting is possible, as is outputting to `dict` or iteration with `print`.

```
print(df)

          color            name
1           Red      McDonald's
2        Orange         Wendy's
2        Purple         Cookout
3        Yellow        Longhorn
4         Green          Subway
5          Blue        Chipotle
6        Indigo       Taco Bell
7        Violet   Steak n Shake
7      Dark Red       Five Guys
8   Dark Orange         Wendy's
9          Aqua  Firehouse Subs
10      Magenta      McDonald's
```